# Finding a single row that matches a dynamically criterium set by examining other rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

Consider the following (pseudo)-code.

```
int aMin = 10
int bMax = 0

Row selectedRow

foreach(row in rows):
  if (row.a <= aMin && row.b >= bMax)
    aMin = row.a
    bMax = row.b
    selectedRow = row

selectedRow
```

Is it possible to write a SQL equivalent of what this is doing, keep tracking of the current lowest value of a and highest of a, to find the single row that matches the criterium?

Comment: RDMS, sample data and desired results would be more helpful

Comment: Why should only a single row match the criterium?   What if there are multiple identical rows?   Also what if the lowest a and the highest b aren't on the same row?

Comment: @TabAlleman, i think in C#, this is not a problem, because it will locate the current row that need to be updated

Comment: True, these questions aren't applicable to C#, and if a SQL based sequential solution is desired, then LONG's answer works.   But if a set-based approach is desired (and why else would you want to do it in SQL?), then these questions need to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @aMin int = 10
DECLARE @bMax int = 0 
DECLARE @a int
DECLARE @b int

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
(
SELECT a,b,--maybe more columns here
FROM your_table
)

OPEN table_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @a, @b

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

if @a < @aMin and @b > @bMax 
BEGIN
UPDATE your_table -- **PLEASE NOTE HERE THIS UPDATE IS RISKY TO EXECUTE, YOU MAY WANT TO RETURN MORE COLUMNS IN THE CURSOR TO MAKE THE ROWS FOR UPDATING UNIQUE**
SET a = @Min, b = @bMax
WHERE a = @a and b = @b
END

SELECT a,b, --maybe more columns here
FROM your_table 
where a = @a and b = @b

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @a, @b
END

CLOSE table_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```

I think the better performance for this is to add identity column for each row so that in the cursor update, you could locate unique row by `Where a = @a and b = @b and identity_row = @i <-- another variable you declared for storing row identifier`